# Reset problem with date picker - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have implemented carbon-datepicker in angular 2 reactive form. A form containing a bunch of fields along with a date picker as well and for the form resetting purpose I have written a method. For the first time date reset is working fine, but for the second time if you provide a date and try to reset it, the reset is not working. But in the console the date value is changing to null but the front end is still showing the date.

This is how I normally reset:

```js
reset(){
this.formControlName.reset();
}
```

Could any one have idea please help me.

Comment: `patchValue` will help you in this situation, here is the documentation https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like problem with carbon-datepicker ngModel. Check ngModel should be two way binding in date picker.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it sounds like a hacky mess to do it like this, but since I had encountered similar issues, this is what you could do.

Let's say you could define ngModel Attribute.

```
[(ngModel)]="datePicker"
```

After that, in the same method you do your form.reset() you could manually asign an empty string into it like

```
this.datePicker = "";
```

Comment: I tried this in a similar fashion and it works. Could you show me the HTML and the class you're trying to achieve this?